# How to get zoom level of an App in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, zooming

I am creating an app using phonegap. On my page I just render an image and then I put some mapping on it using Javascript by getting the image size to locate. If the user clicks that link even you zoom it on computer browser.

```
var img = new Image();
var imgheight = 0;
var imgwidth = 0;

//This loads the original image to a variable
var img = new Image();
//define onload function of variable
img.onload = function() {
    imgheight = this.height
    imgwidth = this.width;

    var factorw = $('#'+imgId).width() / imgwidth;
    var factorh = $('#'+imgId).height() / imgheight;
    //these numbers are the default location of the link from the image
    var x1 = factorw * 9;
    var x2 = factorw * 285;
    var y1 = factorh * 150;
    var y2 = factorh * 250;
}
img.src = $('#sampleImg').attr('src');
```

But now when I debug it on a device, it seems that mobile device has different zoom. When I try to zoom in the image from the device and try to click the link, it's not responding. It only responds when i click on the same place where I put the link.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did u get the answer ?? I am also facing the same problem, if u got answer pls post her

Comment: I just came up with other solution. I use div for may mapping, my div acts like a link.